# Can't install composer on my shared hosting using ssh

Tags: php, composer-php

Trying different methods to install composer on my shared host using putty. But every time I am getting this error.

Timed out error:

[image: error]

I Googled and tried a lot of solutions, but nothing worked. How can I find the exact problem and solution?

Comment: Have you tried just getting the installer on your local machine, the transferring it yourself via SFTP?

Comment: I downloaded  composer-setup.exe, but the linux hosting doesn't supports exe files. I tried downloading installer and getting this error---2016-07-28 14:21:24--  http://installer/
Resolving installer... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `installer'

Comment: also tried instlling using curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php, this time getting curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2001:41d0:a:7b19::2: Network is unreachable error..

Comment: *exe* is Windows. Did you even [read the instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/)? You run each of those 4 `php …` commands one after the other (as long as the previous command worked). And read the options for it since you're doing a *local* install, i.e. only available to your account.

Comment: Yes, I have read all the instructions very carefully. The documentation is saying to use 'php composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin --filename=composer', It gives error 'Could not open input file: composer-setup.php'. Watched a video on youtube, they said use 'wget https://getcomposer.org/installer', it produces the error timed out and after googling I found from saomewhere to run 'curl -sS getcomposer.org/installer | php', and it shows 'network is unreachable'. Can you please tell me exact syntax of installing composer to the root directory of my shared hosting.

Comment: I am doing it using puTTY on windows 10 operating system and the hosting service is provided by Bigrock.

Comment: looks like you're starting with step 3 of those 4 instructions I mentioned. Try starting at 1. You can replace the 3rd command with the one you tried. After all 4 have run, make sure `$HOME/bin` is in your `$PATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run each or these commands in order:

1. php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
2. php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
3. php composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin --filename=composer
4. rm composer-setup.php

Comment: The first command runs but gives no output. Second command echo 'installer corrupt'.

Comment: Okay. That URL just points to PHP source code in text form, so you can download it to your machine, the transfer it to your host with SFTP, then try. However, I think your problems may be worse than that, like the IP is blocked by the Composer site or something.

Comment: My bad luck... Got a new error while executing the third command 'none of the 0 stable version(s) of composer matches your php version (5.5.36 / ID: 50536)'. Also find a solution to install cert bundle and set it's path to php.ini file. But there is no php.ini file in my host.

Comment: There would be a `php.ini`, but not within your home directory, nor will you have write access to it. You may be able to use [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php).